# How to restart Portal Server without start and stop

Tags: shell, websphere-portal

I want to restart the portal Server.suppose if we do like this means 1st execute stopServer.bat WebSphere_Portal -user **** -password **** and 2nd execute startServer.bat WebSphere_Portal

yeah it will start the Server.otherwisewe can do like this also..

stopServer.bat WebSphere_Portal -user **** -password **** && startServer.bat WebSphere_Portal

Myquestion is How to create another batch File ,in that batch File ,it will restart the Server,BY using that 2 batch File.and How to pass that Parameter means username and Password and WebSphere_Portal?

Comment: Why would this be different from writing *any* Windows batch script? I can't see anything here specific to WebSphere Portal.

Comment: I want to create one batch File like..restartServer.bat ..In that Batch,we have to add 2 batch file content..Hope so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference between writing a batch script to restart Portal, and writing a batch script that would call any other batch script:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set USER=%1
set PASSWORD=%2
call stopServer.bat WebSphere_Portal -user %USER% -password %PASSWORD%
call startServer.bat WebSphere_Portal
```

The call it:

```
restartPortal.bat MyUser MyPassword
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add Portal as a windows service and then you can start, stop and restart with the Windows GUI.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21397335

Comment: ... Only if you have admin access to the box.